# Android Studio 3.2.1 Build error Hash String Error

Tags: android, android-studio

I was trying to run some code for a Tinder swipe card feature and I got this error:

Failed to find target with hash string 'android-26' in: /Users/cassandracampbell/Library/Android/sdk

What exactly does that mean?

Comment: [Check this](https://forums.bignerdranch.com/t/failed-to-find-target-with-hash-string-android-26-in/13827/2). If all of that is good, try resetting the cache. `File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart`

Comment: You need to install Android platform version 26 (SDK). Or `/Users/cassandracampbell/Library/Android/sdk/platforms` directory and find the platform version available and replace it with 26. Then sync the project.

Comment: @Shashanth How can I see the SDK version I have now?

Comment: Read my previous comment properly. Clearly mentioned `/Users/cassandracampbell/Library/Android/sdk/platforms`

Comment: @Shashanth Disregard my last comment. I figured it out.

Comment: No problem :) Does it works?